# PDF file renaming according to metadata?

Tags: pdf, document

Is there something I can use that renames PDF files according to their content? Basically an equivalent of http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=27620 in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If you are comfortable with python** you could use the script on http://blog.matt-swain.com/post/25650072381/a-lightweight-xmp-parser-for-extracting-pdf-metadata-in. I have just tested the scripts he provides (for a start, you can `pip install pdfminer`) and they work nicely. The result they give is something along the lines of:

```
[{'ModDate': "D:20050422142709+02'00'", 'CreationDate': "D:20050422142709+02'00'", 'Producer': 'Mac OS X 10.3.8 Quartz PDFContext', 'Creator': 'Word'}]
```

That output you could use to rename your files.

Comment: I have actually assumed thus far that you mean *metadata* with *content* (based on your link). There is also a good tool for academic information retrieval available. It is called [pdfmeat](http://code.google.com/p/pdfmeat/).

Answer (score 7):

This is very easy to achieve with [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/).

For instance, the following command would rename all files in the current directory to `<title>.extension`:

```
exiftool '-filename<$title.%e' .
```

You can install exiftool on Ubuntu with:

```
sudo apt-get install libimage-exiftool-perl
```

---

Please consult the official documentation for more information:

http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/filename.html

Answer (score 3):

There is another alternative. You could `sudo apt-get install pdftk`. With that library you can run a command like `pdftk myfile.pdf dump_data` which results in something in a set of `info` and `value`:

```
InfoKey: Creator
InfoValue: Word
InfoKey: Producer
InfoValue: Mac OS X 10.3.8 Quartz PDFContext
InfoKey: ModDate
InfoValue: D:20050422142709+02'00'
InfoKey: CreationDate
InfoValue: D:20050422142709+02'00'
PdfID0: d7af25c8df737276d8d6b5de49d94d92
PdfID1: d7af25c8df737276d8d6b5de49d94d92
NumberOfPages: 58
```

Again you could use that information in a renaming script. If feel the latter is something best customized because it depends on whether you just want the title, title-author, or something else.

[Source](http://jkwiens.com/2010/01/04/changing-pdf-metadata-on-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an out-of-the-box solution and your PDFs are academic in nature, you might try [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/), the Firefox plugin.

Unfortunately this takes several steps to do, each of which can be a bit slow if you are trying to work with a lot of PDFs at once:

1. Drag and drop your PDFs into Zotero.
2. Right-click them to retrieve the metadata (and automatically download the bibliographic information).
3. If the files were recognized correctly, right-click them again to automatically rename.
4. Export or directly move the renamed files where you want them.

The answer to [a similar question on Superusers](https://superuser.com/questions/269058/automatic-pdf-renaming-based-on-title) shows how to do the same thing using [Mendeley](http://www.mendeley.com/). In Zotero this process can be further automated using [Zotfile](http://www.zotfile.com). Finally, here is [an extensive list](https://csxstatic.ist.psu.edu/downloads/software) of potentially useful tools along these lines.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in search of a GUI solution [KRename](https://userbase.kde.org/KRename)  is a very powerful renaming tool, able to handle your requirements.

[image]

to install:

```
sudo apt install krename
```